# How to change the resolution of maps exported from QGIS Time Manager

Tags: qgis, export, timemanager

Is it possible to change the default resolution of the 'Save as image' export option - which is used by the Time Manager plugin - to export higher quality images that can be used in animations/movies?

I've dug deep into the settings and even the ones I'm warned not to go into, but can't find anything.

Comment: I think the TM plugin works (as you say) by repeatedly doing a ‘save as image’ on the canvas for each frame, so it’s restricted by your monitor’s resolution (and the size of surrounding GUI elements like docks, toolbars and the like)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently, you **cannot** increase the resolution while exporting, there is an open Issue for that feature:
https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues/229